# How would one refer to someone else's lover in 尊敬語?

Tags: word-choice, words, politeness, honorifics, sonkeigo

I've searched the internet, but can't really find anything. My first thoughts were お恋人 and お付き合いの方, but the first doesn't seem very common, and the latter seems to have a different meaning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot say 「お恋人{こいびと}」; That sounds very weird.  「お付{つ}き合{あ}いの方{かた}」 is okay.

Other natural-sounding expressions would include:

・交際相手{こうさいあいて}の方{かた}

・交際されている方

・お相手{あいて}の方

・お相手の男性{だんせい}/女性{じょせい}（の方）

・お付{つ}き合{あ}いされている方

・恋人{こいびと}の～～さん/～～氏{し}

Answer (score 4):

As a hotel reception, the word might be "お連れの方" due to be polite and avoid mistaken.

Formal 丁寧語 it would be お付き合いなさっておいでの方

尊敬語 doesn't apply this case, I think no one knows her.　お恋人 is a typical wrong usage as same as おビール